# Создать datepicker с выбором промежутка по датам

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

Как мне создать кнопку с переходом на следующий datepicker, чтобы в итоге в TextField отображался выбранный промежуток по дате?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно больше кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в общем один из вариантов логики:

При нажатии на кнопку дальше можно подставить новый datepicker или использовать тот же но занулить дату.
Например:

1. Выбираем начальную дату
2. Нажимаем кнопку дальше
3. Запоминаем начальную дату в переменную и скидываем дату в datepicker или показываем новый datepicker
4. Выбираем вторую дату
5. Жмем кнопку готово
6. Запоминаем в переменную дату конца

Таким образом у нас получаеться 2 даты, например:

```swift
var startDate: Date
var endDate: Date
```

А дальше просто записываем в TextField отформатированные две даты, например:

```swift
myTextField.text = startDate.getStr() + " - " + endDate.getStr()

// Расширение что бы удобно и быстро брать с Date строковое представление
extension Date {
    func getStr(format: String = "d MMM y") -> String {
        let formatter3 = DateFormatter()
        formatter3.dateFormat = format
        return formatter3.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивай ;)